# Uploading an image via IIS inherits ReportServer permission and the file appears broken

Tags: php, image, iis

I am using a PHP based application called CiviCRM which allows us to upload images via the KCFinder image uploader. The server is a Windows 2012 RS with IIS 8. The image gets uploaded correctly and also shows in the preview. However, Once I click away from the preview the image appears broken on the page. Even going to the URL on the browser shows the image broken. I tried the same thing for PDFS and same issue. If I login to the server and check the pdf and image it shows that it is uploaded correctly and I can even click on it. I checked further and there seems to be a user group called ReportServer. I tried searching for this group but could not find it. If I change the permission of this group to write or anything else it fixes the issue. Does anyone have any ideas?[inherited permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8liD.png)